# VBO renders completely white

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vbo

I'm trying to speed up the game that I'm currently developing by using VBO's, since they're faster than immediate mode and display lists.

I've done hours of research, but I haven't found the reason why the problem occurs yet.

Whenever I render the VBO, it renders completely white (trying to render a skybox with textures.)

Here's the code for both of the VBO classes

```
    public abstract class VBO {


    public static TexVBO create(double vertices[], double texCoords[], Texture tex)
    {
        int vertexId, textureId;
        DoubleBuffer Bvertex, Btexture;

        vertexId = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexId);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Bvertex = dBuf(vertices), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        textureId = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureId);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Btexture = dBuf(texCoords), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        return new TexVBO(
                vertexId, textureId,
                vertices.length / 3, texCoords.length / 2,
                Bvertex, Btexture,
                tex.getTextureId(),
                7);
    }

    public abstract void draw();
    public abstract void delete();


    private static DoubleBuffer dBuf(double d[])
    {
        DoubleBuffer buf = BufferUtils.createDoubleBuffer(d.length);
        buf.put(d);
        buf.flip();
        return buf;
    }
}
```

and the TexVBO class:

```
public class TexVBO extends VBO {

    private int vertexArrayId, textureArrayId, texId;
    private int vexCount, texCount;
    private int drawMode;
    private DoubleBuffer vertexArray, textureArray;

    public TexVBO(int vertexArrayId, int textureArrayId, int vertexCount, int texCount, DoubleBuffer vertexArray, DoubleBuffer textureArray, int texId, int drawMode)
    {
        this.vexCount = vertexCount;
        this.texCount = texCount;
        this.vertexArrayId = vertexArrayId;
        this.textureArrayId = textureArrayId;
        this.texId = texId;
        this.drawMode = drawMode;
        this.vertexArray = vertexArray;
        this.textureArray = textureArray;
    }

    public void draw()
    {
        // Bind the texture

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);




        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArrayId);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_DOUBLE, 0, 0);

        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureArrayId);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_DOUBLE, 0, 0);

        // Unbind the array buffer.
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        // Draw the vertices.
        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, vexCount);




        // Disable some client states.
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        // Unbind the texture
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }

    public void delete()
    {
        glDeleteBuffers(vertexArrayId);
        glDeleteBuffers(textureArrayId);
    }

}
```

this is the result: http://prntscr.com/hl8nue
The background is supposed to show a skybox. It works when I use immediate mode and display lists...

Comment: It's being called from the rendering loop:
glRotated(m.thePlayer.smoothPitch, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glRotated(m.thePlayer.smoothYaw, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        skyboxVbo.draw();

        glTranslated(-m.thePlayer.position.x, -m.thePlayer.position.y - 1, -m.thePlayer.position.z);

Comment: Since you say that "[it] works when [you] use immediate mode", it could be of use to us if you shared that code, provided that you still have it. "Whenever I render the VBO, it renders completely white": Is white the `glClearColor` colour? If it's not, then it is rendering, which would make this a texturing issue, not a VBO one. Additionally, check for errors with `glGetError` to make sure you didn't pass something invalid to a function somewhere. Also, there is no need to unbind OpenGL objects. As long as you bind things where they are needed, everything will work.